# SharePoint 2016 Custom Timer Job Not Showing in Job Definition

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, central

I am stuck into something really strange behavior of SharePoint.
I have a SharePoint 2016 farm solution. which contains 5 timer jobs classes.
When I change something in any job class. all of the sudden any one of these 5 jobs stop showing in job definition. and after 1 month it again start to show up in the definition.
Moreover, if I create a new solution and create any job in it and deploy, it also doesn't show up in the job definition.

List of jobs

[image]

Job definition

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Feature EventReviever to add and configure the Job in Job Definitions?

[image: Feature Event Receiver SP Timer Job Job]

This will add the job in Jobs Definition Section and Deactivating Feature will Remove the Job if you activate the Feature.

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        try
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate ()
            {
                SPWebApplication parentWebApp = (SPWebApplication)properties.Feature.Parent;
                DeleteExistingJob(JobName, parentWebApp);
                CreateJob(parentWebApp);
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            try
            {
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate ()
                {
                    SPWebApplication parentWebApp = (SPWebApplication)properties.Feature.Parent;
                    DeleteExistingJob(JobName, parentWebApp);
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

If this is not the issue and you have a Feature Event Reciever then share the cs file here.